# What is better: WHERE n = 0 or WHERE n != 1

Tags: mysql

I'm making a lot of times a query which have almost always a condition for "hidden" status in Mysql DB.

A piece is this:

```
...
WHERE `price` >= '7500'
AND `ads`.`subcat_id` = '22'
AND `recycle_bin` != 1
AND `hidden` =0
...
```

So, an idea came into my mind... what's most optimal?
This:

```
AND `recycle_bin` != 1
```

or this:

```
AND `recycle_bin` = 0
```

or both?

Comment: Since it is a boolean, you can use either. I don't think there is a standard to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Of course, just wondering if is a nanosecond better one from another, jejeje

Comment: What happens when you benchmark?

Comment: [It's style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrdBL.jpg)

Comment: Speed-wise it shouldn't matter. In this case however I would use `!=` over `=` depending on your table structure the value could be empty and giving you unexpected  results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing it, you can appreciate that the elapsed time is the same, but there are differences in CPU time. For a table with ~10k rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table where field = 0;
```

returns **CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 32 ms.** 
And if you do:

```
SELECT * FROM table where field != 1;
```

returns **CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 32 ms**.

Comment: I have now 152k rows

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it makes no difference  , both options are as optimal and as efficient , I think it's more of a personal preference